# How generate .proto from python variable?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

For example:

How convert this to .proto ?

```
a = []
```

and I want get this:

```
message SomeName {
    repeated float a = 1;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).

Comment: @spectras , I have not found anything about  generating of .proto files

Comment: Because you're supposed to be the one writing them, and then the compiler will build the python interface. Not the other way around.

Comment: But I want other way around)

Comment: Life is hard. No, seriously, the other way around as you say doesn't make any sense. That's just not how the whole paradigm works. First you define your interface, then you go about using it and/or implementing it.

Comment: Well, it's sadly. But I found solve my task without generating .proto. Thank you for comments!